# Filter out data from the datatable based on the selection from the user

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

Scenario:

I need to filter out data from the datatable based on the selection that has been made from the user. To implement this I have a tree control which represents the hierarchy of the data in the datatable. When a user unchecks a certain node in the tree. That data should be taken out from the datatable.

Question:

- How do I filter "out" data from the datatable?
- If I use search() method, it gives me that matched rows and I want the opposite of this. I need to take out the matched rows instead of showing them.
- I tried using the following filter function but it gives me the filtered data.

  ```
  table.column([column number]).data().filter(function (value, index) {});
  ```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: An example on JSFiddle would be really helpful

Comment: you can also try out my yadcf plugin for datatables it has dozens of options to play with and lots of filter types http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/ and it can filter multiple columns at once too http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_multi_columns_tables_1.10.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to invert the filter. i.e. change the filter to  return false where it currently returns true and vice versa.

You can also do this with search, by inverting the regex you look for.

Comment: How would I invert the regex? Can you please give me an example. Thanks

Comment: I meant invert it in table.search() function.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own custom search function:

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var match = true;
    $(".checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
      var cb = $(this);
      var id = $(this).attr('id');

      if (aData.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(id) >= 0) {
        match = false;
      } else {
        match = true;
      }
    });
    return match;
  });
```

Please see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/en9rh3ap/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer